# Getting Varible passed in State

Tags: lightning-apps

I have one controller that is calling another and passing an ID.  I know I have the state set correctly because on my calling component, this:

```
component.set("v.GroupStructuresList",GroupStructuresList);
console.log('1111' + JSON.stringify(component.get("v.GroupStructuresList")));
```

Produces this:

```
1111{"type":"standard__component","attributes":{"componentName":"c__GroupStructuresList"},"state":{"Aid":"001q000000nv4YTAAY"}}
```

How do I use that variable in the component that I am navigating to?  In the component that is being called I have this:

```
component.set("v.Aid", pageReference.state.Aid);
console.log('1111' + JSON.stringify(component.get("v.Aid")));
```

But my console result shows this: 1111undefined

Thank you!!!

Fred

Comment: the state should probably be {"c__Aid":"001q000000nv4YTAAY"} and in your another component you can get it by console.log(component.get("v.pageReference").state.c__Aid;)

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!!!!!  That made all the difference in the world. I appreciate you taking the time to help me!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Pass the attribute like this from the first component with following state

```
 {"c__Aid":"001q000000nv4YTAAY"}
```

and in your another component you can get it by

```
 console.log(component.get("v.pageReference").state.c__Aid;);
```